# Can I use sitemap_products_generating_before event to modify Product Sitemap in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.4, plugin, sitemaps

In Magento 1, `sitemap_products_generating_before` event allows us to modify the Product Sitemap.

Can I use sitemap_products_generating_before event names in Magento 2.4?

I want to filter the product collection with my custom product attribute:
`addFieldToFilter('use_in_sitemap',['eq' => 1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no related events for `sitemap_products_generating_before` in Magento 2.

To modify production collection for sitemap, you can use `after` method plugin to `getCollection` method in `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product` class which is located in [`vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Sitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php)

As of Magento 2.2.1, Magento introduce a new `prepareSelectStatement` method in `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product` class which is located in [`vendor/magento/module-sitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Sitemap/Model/ResourceModel/Catalog/Product.php). You can user `after` method plugin to that method to change the `select` statement to get Product collection.

Related documents:

- Plugin: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/

---

**Update as your addition request:**
`getCollection` method of `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product` class does not return an object collection like others, it return an array or boolean.

In case you want to add a custom filter based on your custom product attribute, there are 2 solutions:

1. Use `afterPrepareSelectStatement` plugin method instead of `afterGetCollection`.

Here you should take a look at `_addFilter` to know how to apply filter by product attribute.

**Note**: This solution will take longer time than the 2nd solution (using `preference`) but this solution allows you to prevent conflict between your customize with Magento code base in the future Magento version upgrade or other 3rd-party extensions (modules) which customize/override `_addFilter`, `_getAttribute` and `_joinAttribute` methods in `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product` class.

2. Use `preference` to override `prepareSelectStatement` method in `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product` class.

`prepareSelectStatement` method in your custom module should looks like this:

```
public function prepareSelectStatement(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select)
{
    $this->_addFilter($store->getId(), 'use_in_sitemap', 1);

    return $this->_select;
}
```

**Note**: This solution just take a little time for the first implement but it might be lead to conflict between your customize with Magento code base in the future Magento version upgrade or other 3rd-party extensions (modules) which customize/override `_addFilter`, `_getAttribute` and `_joinAttribute` methods in `Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\Product` class.

Related documents:

Plugin: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/
Preference: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/build/dependency-injection-file/

Comment: Added afterGetCollection to plugin. The argument is $result. If I simply wanted to operate a filter on a specific attribute, should I have done something like $result->addFieldToFilter('use_in_sitemap', ['eq' => 1])? Updated question. I would be happy if you could take a look and answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to support your addition request, please take a look.